# How do you open a file using Symbian's RFile?

Tags: c++, mobile, symbian

I have just started developing for Symbian. I am currently using Nokia Qt. I am trying to launch another application based on mime type. I currently am following this  [example](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Launching_default_application_based_on_MIME_type). I'd like to attempt to open a .txt file.

I am finding it hard to understand how to create a RFile and what the TDesC16 class actually is / does?

In the example the code which basically does the work is following:

```
// Gets the UID and MIME type for the given file name.
TUid uid;
TDataType dataType;
User::LeaveIfError(session.AppForDocument(aFileName, uid, dataType));

// Runs the default application using the MIME type, dataType.
// You can also use the UID to run the application. 
TThreadId threadId;
User::LeaveIfError(session.StartDocument(aFileName, dataType, threadId));
```

The variable aFileName must be of type RFile. So how would I create this object to open a .txt file stored at Computer\Nokia C7-00\Phone memory\test.txt (in Explorer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TDesC16 is a Symbian descriptor, which is basically a string. Here is a good manual: http://descriptors.blogspot.com/

As for your problem. In the example it looks like aFileName is meant to be a descriptor.
So to open test.txt do something like this:

```
TThreadId threadId;
User::LeaveIfError(session.StartDocument(_L("c:\test.txt"), dataType, threadId));
```

If you want to go with RFile, here is a code sample:

```
RFs fs;
User::LeaveIfError(fs.Connect()); // connect to File Server
CleanupClosePushL(fs); // adding to the cleanup stack to ensure that the resources are released properly if a leave occurres while opening a file

RFile file;
User::LeaveIfError(file.Open(fs, _L("c:\test.txt"), EFileRead));
CleanupClosePushL(file);

// do something with file

CleanupStack::PopAndDestroy(2); // closes file and fs and removes them from the cleanup stack;
```

Comment: Not that it matter anymore with today's announcement by nokia, but: one should not use macro _L() - it has long been scheduled for deprecation. One should use '_LIT()' wherever possible, especially in new code. e.g. ' _LIT(KTestFile, "c:\test.txt") '